# How to restore Android Studio Live Templates to original?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, flutter

I've installed some Dart/Flutter live templates to Android Studio (File/Import settings and imported from Jar file) that messed up everything. How can I restore only the live template settings to the original? I've pressed "Restore deleted defaults" in the live template config page, but It seems to not restore the previous templates. I cannot use the `stful` live template for example (from flutter plugin).

Comment: Currently it's not possible to restore changed templates if settinsg weren't saved previously. Feel free to create request on YouTrack to make it possible: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA. As a workaround you could try to copy "config\templates" folder (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519) from other machine or installation.

Answer (score 0):

You could see your current live templates like Preferences>Live Templates>Dart || Flutter at the Android Studio. It removes the live template when press `-` button, adds with `+` button. It could be edited when clicked double to template. You could take `No applicate contexts yet.` warning. Click to `Define` label and choose dart or flutter where your live template in. Finally select `Top-level`, click `OK`. This fixed my problem. I hope it works for you.